# Drupal 8 buildForm #value

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

In my buildForm :

```
      public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
        {  
         $form['actions']['submit'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => "I don't",
         ];
           return $form;
       }
```

During the render, drupal shows my button like that :'I don't' on my view.html.twig 
how could I fix this problem ? please

I tried #value = 'I don\'t' and I don't' don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :
My theme escape twice the apostrophe. I override my template and add  `|raw`

My templates

```
 <button{{ attributes }}>{{ attributes.value|raw }}</button>{{ children }}
```